# Angular NG8001: 'element' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a HomeComponent from which I want to load a HomeBannerComponent into.

If I create a home.module.ts for the home.component.ts and declare HomeBannerComponent in the home.module.ts the `app-home-banner` I have defined in the HomeBannerComponent file does not load into the home.component.html

However if I back those changes out, and instead declare the HomeBannerComponent in the app.module.ts and then put the component in the app.component.html it works just fine.

Can someone please tell me why that is? The code below is the code where I want it to load in the home.component.html and it breaks with the following error

`NG8001: 'app-home-banner' is not a known element`

**home.component.html**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent { }
```

**home.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { HomeBannerComponent } from '../home-banner/home-banner.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent, HomeBannerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**home-banner.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-banner',
  templateUrl: './home-banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-banner.component.css']
})
export class HomeBannerComponent {

}
```

I am not sure if its relevant to the issue or not, but the "home page" is imported into the app-routing.module.ts.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './resume/resume.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects/projects.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'resume', component: ResumeComponent },
  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: could it be that you just forgot to import your home-module into the app-module?

Comment: You need to import HomeModule, or lazy load the module in the app-routing.

Comment: I have tried loading this into the app-routing.module, app.module, a home.module and not a single method works that allows me to include this in a specific HTML outside of the app.component.html I don't understand why this is breaking